# What about canny merchant's other information?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

The general feat **Wanderer's Diplomacy** (*Player's Handbook II* 85) grants as one of its benefits the ability canny merchant that says

> You can make a Diplomacy check to track down an item that is normally too expensive to be purchased in the town or settlement where you are currently located. The DC of this check is 10 + (the item’s gp cost minus the community’s gp limit, divided by 1,000). If this check succeeds, you learn of a merchant who can supply the item to you. You must still purchase it as normal.

How often can a creature use the ability canny merchant? How long does it take to use the ability canny merchant? Absent official answers, answers based on experience are welcome.

(In case you're interested, the ability canny merchant's formula means that, for example, finding a merchant selling a [*horn of blasting*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#horn-of-blasting) (*DMG* 259) (20,000 gp; 1 lb.) in a thorp requires successful Diplomacy skill check (DC 29), yet finding a merchant selling a *horn of blasting* in a small city only requires a successful Diplomacy skill check (DC 15).)

Comment: I believe that such checks are a once-off deal. From what I recall of the buying and selling rules, once you make the checks for a given town, that's it... the item(s) are either available or they aren't. I seem to vaguely recall a comment that there is no point in checking again until a year or more had gone by, possibly based off the idea of seasonal income that most fantasy era NPCs would go by. I'll see if I can find the stuff I'm vaguely recalling in the DMG or somewhere.

Comment: The GP limit stuff on p137 and the Economics section on p139-140 appear to be about it for guidance. I note that the gp limit seems to be independently invoked for each individual item being bought or sold (based on the grammar) which could potentially cause a whole 'nother batch of problems. At a guess, it would be a per-location based check, and probably only once, but that's my opinion.

Comment: @nijineko I think you're thinking the rate at which a community, exhausted of capital, regains that capital, but that's an interesting idea. Pretty much *just once ever per community* is kind of a bookkeeping nightmare, though, and, really, sort of does little to curb potential abuse: "Find us a *wish* spell in that thorp!" orders the party leader, so the halfling looks for *every different kind of magic item that can tote a* wish *spell* until he's successful… and that's *a lot* of different magic items!

Comment: Exactly! Checking once per possible item abuse is just what I was attempting to point out due to the ambiguous language. Limiting a check to once per community per year per category of request might be the way to go... that way it would cover all "wish type items" for a given community. On the other hand, I think that's where the DM's rule 0 kicks in - "If it's fun or cool or makes sense, the answer is yes; and if it ruins the fun, the cool, or just doesn't make sense, then the answer is no." (no matter how many thorps are checked) ^^

Comment: Personal experience says that it's easier to make one check for the community, but instead of making the check per-item, simply have the character make the check and use the rules for determining the DC to establish the highest value of item that could be tracked down- now you have a full list of every item the character can get using this feat in this community.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog That's a *stunningly* good variant. You should add that to your answer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Fair enough, done.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around the implication that on a failed *canny merchant* Diplomacy check, the curious party simply does not *learn* of a merchant from which to buy such an item. It doesn't suggest it isn't there - merely that they don't learn who to buy it from. Somewhat over-the-top, I know, but allowing a character to take Wanderer's Diplomacy *might* have the unfortunate implication that every single tiny town is hiding every single available item ... but that adventurers never seem to ask the right person in the right way. (Even if it's the same person for each such item!)

Answer (score 3):

Since the feat doesn't give a limit to how often it can be used in the description, and since no special power is being employed, the best way to arbitrate use is to treat it like the Gather Information check it effectively is- the character can check any number of times, but it takes hours of questioning before they find the information they're looking for.  If we continue to use Gather Information as our basis, it should take 1d4+1 hours to make each check, though you may want to assign a modifier based on how much traveling the members of the community do.

Which brings me to a potentially more important point- it looks like you may have read this feat as saying that the character will find the merchant in *that* community.  The feat, however, says only that they will *learn of* a merchant, not where that merchant is.  This is basically a feature that allows you to find out that yes, there is a *ring of three wishes* for sale, somewhere, but the only fellow anybody in town ever heard of carrying it lives over in Waterdeep.  This removes the potential for abuse from any character that doesn't have a *teleport* spell handy... and if they do, might I suggest, "Oh yeah, there IS a guy who sells *vorpal brilliant energy* swords.  Nice Mercane, lives on the Plane of Limbo somewhere."

This last part isn't an interpretation of the feat so much as a cheap way to manage the bookkeeping, but I'd suggest that instead of having a character perform a Diplomacy check for each item, you have them perform the Diplomacy check, and use their result to determine the maximum gp value of an item they could learn about in the community.  To use the example given in the question, rather than saying that the character who succeeds on a DC 29 Diplomacy check in a thorp knows of a merchant selling a *horn of blasting*, you could instead rule that scoring a 29 with their check allows them to know of any merchant selling an item of up to 20,000 gp in value- let the player tell you what item within that limit they're interested in, and you give them a name and a possible location for the merchant.

Comment: I would likely sock a DM that said, "You, while in the thorp, track down a *horn of blasting* for sale… in Waterdeep." That's not a benefit as a PC would've likely found a *horn* readily available there by going there anyway! (The house rule, however, is gold. So, balance, I guess?)

Comment: Given that normally the only way to determine if a particular town has an item is to travel there and look, I'd argue the benefit you're receiving is pinpointing the fellow to talk to, no matter where he is.  In that case, the reduced DC for larger communities makes sense, as there are more information sources available.

Comment: That's not exactly true. The *DMG* says, "Anything having a price under that [town's gp limit] limit is most likely available, whether it be mundane or magical" (137). (I guess we *could* disagree over what *most likely* means — I'd argue that means *spellworms of wish* aren't likely available, but you might argue for something I'd view as more common like *rings of elemental command* —, but that's a *campaign* argument thing and not something the feat itself should be concerned with.)

Comment: Oh, I agree, giving the location of a merchant as one of those metropolises that is already guaranteed to have the item is what we in the biz call "a jerk move."  (That said, I've totally done that very thing as a DM, so... not in the face, please)  This feat is much more useful if the DM is a bit more creative with their location choice, maybe telling the character that there's a traveling merchant two towns over who's known for carrying such items.  I pretty much imagine this feat working as a nonmagical _locate object_ with a much greater range in exchange for the skill check.

Comment: ...and if you don't like that, consider the issue of someone with an excellent diplomacy check and a party full of murderhobos.  Spend a week "finding" treasures "for sale" that are worth more than the inhabitants of the thorp will make in three generations, then murder a dozen or so peasants for the sweet sweet loot.